# Redirecting from one View to another and changing the whole URL codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect, view

I am working on codeigniter and I am making a login page. When i validate the credentials I wan to move the user to next view if the credentials are correct.
I am using following command to redirect the user but it is merging the new view to the existing view and the url being shown in the browser is also getting appended.
$this->load->view('DataEntry');
URL before executing this command :http://127.0.0.1:8080/ci/
URL after executing this command : http://127.0.0.1:8080/ci/index.php/CI/DataEntry

how can i redirect the user from one view to another without appending the url and what is the right way to do it ?
I am an abolute beginner. so accept my apologies for dumb questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it should be something like this:

```
//pseudo code
if ($validation_passed)
{
    redirect('secret_page_controller/secretpage_method');
}
else
{
    //if validation failed
    $this->load->view('view_where_login_form_is');
}
```

Follow basic example from [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html).
Please, format your code appropriate and add controller/method(s) code.

Comment: To use the redirect(); function you will first need to load the url helper.

Comment: @WilliamKnauss You are quite right. And much more than that such is checking for session on 'secret_page' etc. This is just wireframed pseudo code of first steps in login code snippet.